# Webpack UglifyJS remove dead code, but don't minimize code

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

How to remove dead code, but don't minimize code, using Webpack and UglifyJS?

Comment: Three minuses, but not comments, really?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use the [beautifier options](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#beautifier-options). Minimum idea:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  beautify: true
})
```

Comment: See https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compressor-options . Esp. `dead_code`. I read the initial description wrong.

Comment: But whai if I only want to remove dead code and leave everything untouched? Beautifier transforms my code in many different ways.

Comment: Maybe disable everything else then. I have a feeling Uglify wasn't designed particularly that use case in mind so using that feature alone may be tricky.

Comment: I got that feeling too because I already have disabled everything else and it still minimizes (unless I tell it to beutify but as I said before - that also transforms my code)